# How to align AppBar to center Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I have an app with page navigations, and when I navigate to another page, a back arrow appears in the AppBar, which moves the text to the side. And I need it to be constantly in the center

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded), onPressed: () {  },),
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Some text'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(...)
```

This is the AppBar Code

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OrderWidget())
          );
```

In this way I go to a new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Align` your title, set `centerTitle` true in your `AppBar` for center title, like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            title: Text('Some text'),
          ),
```